# Guardar cores selecionadas mesmo indo para outra página

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Alguma ideia de como faço para ter 2 (opções) arrays com estilos para mudar as cores em locais específicos do site (por exemplo mudar 3 classes: .header, .footer, .sidebar), mas manter a opção no qual o usuário clicou mesmo quando ele for para outra página no site?

Comment: `ng-route` mudando o conteúdo da página, mas não mudando de endereço. Tem outro meio mais fácil mas que não é recomendado porque não funciona com Search Engines, etc.

Comment: usa cookies ou localstorage para salvar estas opções

Comment: @DH. obrigada por responder, vc tem um exemplo? Ng-Route do AngularJS é mais complexo do que com jquery/ javascript usando cookkies/localstorage como o Gabriel Rodrigues sugeriu?

Comment: é apenas para exibir como ficaria com outras cores o template

Comment: @DH. qual a forma mais facil?

Comment: Você pode usar cookies também pra manter essas opções, se você não preparou seu site pra usar `ng-route` ou a forma alternativa dele(desculpa mas eu esqueci o nome da função, teria que olhar em casa meus fontes), os cookies são uma boa saída rápida

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira fácil de fazer isso seria usando o $rootScope
Mas cuidado, não é aconselhado guardar funções/ métodos aqui, apenas dados.

Você pode injetar a dependência no seu controller onde o usuário escolhe as cores:

```
myApp.controller('colorChangeCtrl', ['$scope' $rootScope, function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.colors = {
        header: '#fff',
        sidebar: 'rgb(156,236,148)',
        footer: 'alice-blue'
    };
}]);
```

e depois você pode acessar o $rootsScope de qualquer controller injetado ô e receber os valores normalmente:

```
myApp.controller('otherCtrl', ['$scope' $rootScope, function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.chosenColors = $rootScope.colors;
}]);
```

Também pode usar um service, localstorage, cookies e até routes, mas acho assim a forma mais rápida e que demanda menos conhecimento pra ser aplicada.
Mas caso esteja em busca de agregar conhecimento sugiro que busque essas outras alternativas.